# PHP MYSQL - Button to SORT asc/desc

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sorting, button

I am rather stuck on how to create a button that will sort the data in a table printed into a php file as ascending order or descending order.

```
<form name="Table Properties" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 Order by Week
 <button type="submit" name="sort week" class="button" value="1"> Sort Week </button>
 </form>
<?php if('sort week' == true ){
    "SELECT * FROM `classes` ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
}
?>
```

This is a simple example of what I am trying to acheive, I am just stuck on the php code side. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: 'sort week' will never == true, it will equal 'sort week'.  It's a string.

Comment: @Devon: Au contraire.  A loose comparison using `==` of a non-empty string with `TRUE` will *always* be true.  See [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing the whitespace and then capturing it using $_POST..

```
<form name="Table Properties" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 Order by Week
 <button type="submit" name="sort_week" class="button" value="1"> Sort Week </button>
 </form>
<?php if($_POST['sort_week'] === true) {
"SELECT * FROM `classes` ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
}?>
```

Comment: sort_week will not === true...change that to == or === "1" as it will come back as a string.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for, is the $_POST array you get, when POSTing a form to a PHP script or you use $_REQUEST if you don't know if it's a POST or GET method.

```
<?php 
if($_POST["sort week"] == 1 ){
    $query="SELECT * FROM `classes` ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides from what you have already been answered, you should change the value of the button depending on what is pretended to do.

Typically this is done in a sequence: non-sorted, asc, desc.

I mean, the column is not sorted, when you click first time, it gets sorted ASC, if you click again, you sort it DESC, and if you click again you go back to not sorted.

So in your code it would be something like this:

```
<form name="Table Properties" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Order by Week
<?php 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `classes` ";
 $value = 0;
switch($_POST['sort_week']) {
 case 1:
    $value = 2;
    $query .= "ORDER BY `classes`.`week` DESC";
  break;
 case 0:
  $value = 1;
    $query .= "ORDER BY `classes`.`week` ASC";
  break;
 default:
  break;
}
?>
<button type="submit" name="sort_week" class="button" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"> Sort Week </button>
</form>
```